# I am getting this error while creating new HDInsight cluster

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

"You do not have the minimum cores available,12, to create a cluster in Est des Etats-unis, please select different location or subscription".

I tried with two subscriptions and many locations, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request) document to request quota increase for a specific region you are interested in. This is a "routine" operation. Usually takes a couple of days (faster if you have EA support). Once your request if fulfilled you can proceed with creating your cluster.

Each subscription in Azure got its own quotas you have to adhere to. By default you are limited to 10 cores per VM type for most VM types.

Comment: I created a quota increase request and I am waiting for the reply. Thanks.

Comment: The quota increase request was approved and I can now create the cluster. Thanks again.